# Tensorflow: Input Pipeline very slow / does not scale

Tags: multithreading, tensorflow, batch-processing

I'm trying to set up a Tensorflow input pipeline for feeding images into an AlexNet for feature extraction (not for training, this is a one of thing). Since AlexNet is rather small it is crucial to provide input data at a high rate for achieving acceptable performance (~1000 images / second).

My images are 400x300 JPEGs with 24KB per image on average.

Unfortunately it seems, that the Tensorflow input pipeline can't keep up with a GTX1080 running the AlexNet.

My input pipeline is simple: load a file, decode the image, resize it and batch them.

I created a small benchmark to show the issue:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf
import time
import glob
import os

IMAGE_DIR = 'images'
EPOCHS = 1


def main():
    print('batch_size\tnum_threads\tms/image')

    for batch_size in [16, 32, 64, 128]:
        for num_threads in [1, 2, 4, 8]:
            run(batch_size, num_threads)


def run(batch_size, num_threads):
    filenames = glob.glob(os.path.join(IMAGE_DIR, '*.jpg'))
    (filename,) = tf.train.slice_input_producer(
        [filenames],
        capacity=2 * batch_size * num_threads,
        num_epochs=EPOCHS)

    raw = tf.read_file(filename)
    decoded = tf.image.decode_jpeg(raw, channels=3)
    resized = tf.image.resize_images(decoded, [227, 227])

    batch = tf.train.batch(
        [resized],
        batch_size,
        num_threads,
        2 * batch_size * num_threads,
        enqueue_many=True)

    init_op = tf.group(
        tf.global_variables_initializer(),
        tf.local_variables_initializer())

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init_op)

        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

        t = time.time()
        try:
            while not coord.should_stop():
                sess.run(batch)
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            pass
        finally:
            coord.request_stop()

        tpe = (time.time() - t) / (len(filenames) * EPOCHS) * 1000
        print('{: <11}\t{: <10}\t{: <8}'
              .format(batch_size, num_threads, tpe))

        coord.join(threads)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Running this on a MacBook Pro (early 2015, 2,9 GHz Intel Core i5) yields the following results:

```
batch_size      num_threads     ms/image
16              1               4.81571793556
16              2               3.00584602356
16              4               2.94281005859
16              8               2.94555711746
32              1               3.51123785973
32              2               1.82255005836
32              4               1.85884213448
32              8               1.88741898537
64              1               2.9537730217
64              2               1.58108997345
64              4               1.57125210762
64              8               1.57615303993
128             1               2.71797513962
128             2               1.67120599747
128             4               1.6521999836
128             8               1.6885869503
```

It shows overall bad performance far from 1/ms per image. Also it does not scale beyond two threads, which in this case is to be expected since it is a dual core processor only.

Running the same benchmark on a 2.5Ghz AMD Opteron 6180 SE with 24 cores yields the following:

```
batch_size      num_threads     ms/image
16              1               13.983194828
16              2               6.80965399742
16              4               6.67097783089
16              8               6.63090395927
32              1               12.0395629406
32              2               5.72535085678
32              4               4.94155502319
32              8               4.99696803093
64              1               10.9073989391
64              2               4.96317911148
64              4               3.76832485199
64              8               3.82816386223
128             1               10.2617599964
128             2               5.20488095284
128             4               3.16122984886
128             8               3.51550602913
```

Here, too, single threaded / overall performance is very bad and it does not scale beyond 2/4 threads.

The systems are neither IO nor CPU bound in any of the cases. For both systems loading and resizing the images with OpenCV gives far better numbers (~0.86ms/image in the MacBook, which in this case is CPU bound and up to ~0.22ms/image on the server, which in this case is IO bound).

What's going on with Tensorflow here? How can I speed this up?

I already tried to assemble a batch of images manually and use enqueue_many for batching, this made things even worse. I tried to add a small sleep before running the loop, just to make sure the queues are filled - but no luck.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Some performance tuning advice regarding input pipeline on this page might be helpful: https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide; could you give it try?

Comment: One thing you could try is to wrap the input step with CPU with tf.device('/cpu:0'). We will also release a high-performance, reference implementation soon and update the TensorFlow/Performance page with that.